# Visual Studio - Renaming Files From Uppercase to Lowercase

Tags: c#, android, windows, visual-studio, xamarin

## Short Version

I found myself losing alot of time *renaming + including* files in my Xamarin.Forms Projects because any change from Upercase to Lowercase (or vice versa) only in the files, will result in no change what so ever in the Project file, so i have a few questions:

- Is there an option in **Visual Studio** that makes it take into account file **renaming from Upercase to Lowercase**? (*See Edit Below*)
- What's the best way of changing alot of files from **Upercase to Lowercase** without **delete/re-adding** them?
- Is renaming the file includes in the `.csproj` directly a **Good Practice**? if not, what is the best for this kind of scenarios?

---

## Longer Version + Adicional Info

I had to include over 2000 images (Android + iOS and their respective sizes). So i started copying the files into the correct directory and include them in the Mobile Projects, the problem came when i already included the files in the project and some of the files had Uppercase letters that i haven't noticed before, so i made changes by hand to all the files, when i noticed that **those changes weren't reflected in the Solution Explorer/Project File**, i tried manually and got this error:

[image]

> Edit: It seems this issue was apparently [resolved](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/186996/no-more-internal-file-identifiers-available-error.html) in VS2019 arround v.16.1, but only if the file wasn't renamed externally. Since i did that i got this warning. This anwsers my first question.

And one solution that i found was renaming like: `Foo.png > fooo.png > foo.png`

But that would be exponentialy time-consuming by the number of files i had to edit, so i made this piece of code:

```
string filepath = @"C:\Users\(...)";
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);

foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    if (file.Name.Any(char.IsUpper))
    {
        File.Move(file.FullName, file.FullName.Replace(file.Name, file.Name.ToLower()));
    }
}
```

What it does is basically create a new file but with Lowercase, that means i still have to **Remove the old References** and **Include the new Files**. This doesn't seem right since a simple rename would do.

What's my go to option here?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/186996/no-more-internal-file-identifiers-available-error.html

Comment: @HansPassant My version of Visual Studio is 16.3.9, wich came Nov 5, 2019, the accepted awnser on the developercommunity is from May 17, 2019, wich is arround version 16.1 /16.2 preview, the only thing i did diferent was renaming the file directly first before changing in the Solution Explorer, i will try to add a file and rename in the Solution Explorer

Comment: @HansPassant just tried and it worked, renaming the file in the solution explorer without any external changes it didn't give me the error, but the problem remains, because doing bulk file renames in the solution explorer is still slower than just re-adding them, and renaming the files in the folder doesn't reflect in the solution explorer, but very well spotted! i would like if you present this in a form of a Anwser, despite not resolving the issue, it might help other who might need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows as operating system is ascendant of the operating system where there was no difference in lower and uppercase. As such at today's state Windows treats the files with same letters as the same though technically it can remember and display lower and upper cases in file names.

Overall it means your request is not natural in Windows. Maybe someone can provide you with some hack, but if you want to resolve this problem quickly move your project to the Mac where this works differently at the operating system level, perform your operation in Visual Studio for Mac and then you can continue to use Windows if you prefer.

EDIT: Actually I can tell you one hack for Windows. First rename file to whatever you want (like add 1 at the end) and then rename it to the desired file name. It will work properly.

Comment: Or do two renames - add a letter, remove letter and make lowercase. Done.

Comment: on the "Longer Version + Adicional Info" i already provided that "hack" and an way of re-adding the files with lowercase, i was looking for an faster or diferent solution from what i gave, but thank you for the first info you gave me

Comment: @TomTom I think that I have updated the answer before your comment with the same info :).

Comment: To be MORE safe: Rename by adding a new file extension. Then on restart you can look for this one and remove it - so a crash does not leave you with a mangled file name ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case the files were in the .csproj (Project File) with lowercase name. Removing the affected lines from .csproj fixed the problem.

In Visual Studio 2019 -
Right click on the project name in Solution Explorer ->  select "Edit Project File"

Find the offending file under ItemGroup, you can either remove the line or edit the filename. I have not had any side effects by removing the file as I know what I am doing, your mileage might differ.

Just incase cut and paste the delete or rename before hand in Notepad in case you want to go back, Ctrl-z works too :)